# db null coming in property asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, dbnull

i am getting error in the code **getting error
The value for column 'TotalValue' in table 'wsm_View_PurchaseOrderList' is DBNull.**

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28bLi.png)

```
public decimal TotalValue {
    get {

        try {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(tablewsm_View_PurchaseOrderList.TotalValueColumn, DBNull.Value)) {
                return 0.0;
            } else {
                return Convert.ToDecimal(this(this.tablewsm_View_PurchaseOrderList.TotalValueColumn));
            }

        } catch (System.InvalidCastException e) {
            throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'TotalValue' in table 'wsm_View_PurchaseOrderList' is DBNull" + ".", e);
        }
    }
    set { this(this.tablewsm_View_PurchaseOrderList.TotalValueColumn) = value; }
}
```

Comment: The error is explanatory. The value on your tablewsm_View_PurchaseOrderList.TotalValueColumn is null.

Comment: how to handle it ?

Comment: What is the Data type of TotalValueColumn? You can check if the value is null or not and use 0 if its null.

Comment: money-datatype total value col.

Comment: `TotalValueColumn` seems have `DBNull` value when it assigned to non-null `decimal` equivalent. Probably certain check against `DBNull.Value` is possible.

Comment: how to handle db null ?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto have handled this in code but still happening

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for DBNull like this:

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull(tablewsm_View_PurchaseOrderList.TotalValueColumn))
{
    return 0.0;
}
```